# Razor page hubConnection doesn't get async message

Tags: .net, razor, signalr, blazor

This is form in razor page:

```
<div>
    <b>Message :</b> <input value="@Context" @onchange="@(e => { Context = e.Value.ToString(); })" />
    <button class="btn btn-default" @onclick="@(() => HubConnection.SendAsync("Message", TableId, @playerName, @Context))">Send</button>
</div>
```

this is my MultiplayerHub function:

```
 public async Task Message(string tableId, string playername, string context)
        {
            await Clients.GroupExcept(tableId, Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("NewMessage", playername, context);
        }
```

and Im receiving "NewMessage" in razor page this way:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
        HubConnection.On<string, string>("NewMessage", (playername, context) => {
            messages.Add(new Message(playername, context));
        });
}
```

Problem is that I can't receive signal from hub and add item to list. Form works and it correctly sends variables and message to MultiplayerHub, but then nothing more happens. Does someone know how can I fix it?
I have another functions similar to this and it works correct.
Github project: https://github.com/dawid628/CheckersApp

Edit:
When I use Clients.All.SendAsync(...) it works, but to all hubs.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I resolved problem. I changed

```
await Clients.GroupExcept(tableId, Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("NewMessage", playername, context);
```

for

````
await Clients.Group(tableId).SendAsync("NewMessage", playername, context);```
````

Comment: So the issue was you where checking from the excluded connectionId?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, just checked this func and it worked.